# How to remove a second '+' character from telephone string using python

Tags: python, python-re

e.g. string +444401608+642055

need to remove any '+' characters unelss the '+' is in the first position of the string.

Prefereably using the 're' python library.

+444401608+642055 -> +444401608642055

+4444+01608+642+055 -> +444401608642055

thanks in advance!!

Comment: There's not really any need to use `re` when you can just use `foo[0] + foo[1:].replace('+', '')`.

Comment: @Axe319. Thakns for pointing out there is a simpler option. Can you detail it as an code asnwer please as I am quite new to Python. Many thanks!

Comment: I added it as an answer along with a regex alternative.

Comment: @Axe319, you are an absolute star. thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use:

```
foo = '+444401608+642055'
bar = foo[0] + foo[1:].replace('+', '')
print(bar)
```

This assumes your string has at least one character (`foo[0]`). It works because if `foo[0]` isn't a `+` we can safely ignore it in the `str.replace()` anyway. `foo[1:]` is just the rest of your string from the first character on.

If you really want to use regex you could use:

```
import re
foo = '+444401608+642055'
bar = re.sub(r'(?<!^)\+', '', foo)
print(bar)
```

`(?<!)` is a negative look behind.

`^` indicates the start of a line.

`\+` matches the character `+` literally.

So in other words, look for every `+` character that isn't immediately preceded by a line start and replace with `''` or nothing.

https://regex101.com/r/om6Z1j/2